# Why do I get NameError when I run a rack app with "rackup"?

Tags: ruby, rack, rackup

I'm having trouble running a rack app using `rackup`.

This is my config.ru:

```
$:.unshift "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/lib/"
require 'blogrite'

run Blogrite::Server.new(:with => :test)
```

Calling `rackup config.ru` throws:

```
[~/Code/blogrite master] rackup config.ru 
/Users/josemota/Code/blogrite/lib/blogrite/server.rb:2:in `<module:Blogrite>': uninitialized constant Blogrite::Server (NameError)
from /Users/josemota/Code/blogrite/lib/blogrite/server.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/josemota/Code/blogrite/config.ru:5:in `block in <main>'
...
```

You can check the full project in [Github](http://github.com/josemota/blogrite). I do not understand the reason I get `NameError`.

Comment: Does it work fine if you do a `require 'blogrite/server'` instead of autoload?

Comment: _Update_: It does. Is autoload screwed up? ¶ @Dogbert It has worked before. I don't know why it won't now. Let me check it out.

Comment: I haven't used `autoload` ever. Someone who has may be able to answer it better.

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert, I shall ask to the proper person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for this error to come up. The NameError shown is fired from the module, which won't recognize the paths correctly.

@Dogbert correctly pointed out that autoload was probably not working. According to Dave Barker in [his post](http://kzar.co.uk/blog/view/autoload-uninitialized-constant-nameerror), the class that autoloads must include the current path in `$:` / `$LOAD_PATH`. I did that and now it works.

The [resulting commit](https://github.com/josemota/blogrite/commit/a26b1cc5d09c5d9c7495d337d7c439f5fc1552a1) is now available. Thanks @Dogbert for pointing the autoload issue in the first place!